# What is the size of The Python Tools For Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, size

Can someone please tell me the approximate size of python tools for visual studio, i have a limited data plan so i want to know whether or not i should start to download it

Answer (score 0):

To support Python language and support intellisense for Python the package is apporx 1.5MB
Refer this link to download directly the exe for python support
https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/python/